# Подсчитать среднее значение

Tags: prolog

Привет. Выясняю средний возраст читателей. Сначала складываю возраст всех читателей , а затем делю на количество читателей(путём счётчика).Выдаёт неправильный результат и тут я запутался.В чём ошибка?

```
DOMAINS

avtor,nazv_kn,izdatel,fio,adres,mesto_rab,fakt_vozv,data_vz,data_vozv=string
shifr,god_izda,kol_str,telefon,vozrast,kol=integer
 stringList=string*
   list = integer*

FACTS
determ sum(kol)
determ sum1(kol)

PREDICATES

nondeterm kniga(shifr,avtor,nazv_kn,izdatel,god_izda,kol_str).
nondeterm chitatel(fio,adres,telefon,vozrast,mesto_rab).
nondeterm dolzhnik(fio,nazv_kn, data_vz,fakt_vozv).
nondeterm ychet_karta(fio,shifr,data_vz,data_vozv,fakt_vozv).

nondeterm ychet_karta(string,integer,string,string,string).
nondeterm sr_vozrast(integer,integer).
nondeterm sred(real).

spisok_4ita
pr1(list,integer,integer)      
pr2(real)

CLAUSES

kniga(1,"Tolstoi","VIM","D",1995,2506).
kniga(2,"Keroll","ASS","M",2003,1500).
kniga(3,"Doyl","XAS","A",1976,1300).
kniga(4,"Stoker","DER","A",1993,1876).
kniga(5,"Pyshkin","KE","E",1999,450).
kniga(6,"Akynin","PES","E",2001,850).
kniga(7,"Uells","VEV","M",2008,1600).

chitatel("Si","Mo",80670,21,"Prestij").
chitatel("Iv","Mi",30870,30,"Fabrika").
chitatel("Ka","So",10341,45,"Tantal").
chitatel("Sa","Le",40310,18,"Moststroy").
chitatel("Ka","Te",21,45687,"Bankir").

ychet_karta("Si",7,"20.01.13","19.02.13","da").
ychet_karta("Si",4,"20.01.13","_","net").
ychet_karta("Iv",5,"15.01.13","_","net").
ychet_karta("Iv",2,"16.01.13","_","net").
ychet_karta("Ka",2,"28.02.13","15.03.13","da").
ychet_karta("Sa",4,"21.02.13","_","net").
ychet_karta("Sa",6,"08.02.13","06.03.13","da").
ychet_karta("Ka",1,"25.01.13","_","net").

/*Zdec vbIchisl9IO sredniy vozrast chitatel9*/
sr_vozrast(K,L):-assert(sum(0)),assert(sum1(0)),chitatel(_,_,_,X,_),retract(sum(S)),S1=S+X,asserta(sum(S1)),retract(sum1(N)),N1=N+1,asserta(sum1(N1)),fail.
sr_vozrast(K,L):-retract(sum(K)),retract(sum1(L)).
sred(R):-sr_vozrast(S,N),R=S/N.

GOAL sred(R).
```

Comment: Давайте вы уменьшите простыню до минимального примера, воспроизводящего проблему. Неужели `fio`, `adres`, `mesto_rab` существенны для вашего примера?

Comment: Как-то так;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На Visual prolog 5.2 :
FACTS
single sum(integer)

single count(integer)

PREDICATES

nondeterm chitatel(fio,adres,telefon,vozrast,mesto_rab)

nondeterm sr_vozrast(integer)

CLAUSES
sum(0).
count(0).

chitatel("Si","Mo",80670,8,"Prestij").

chitatel("Iv","Mi",30870,7,"Fabrika").

chitatel("Ka","So",10341,6,"Tantal").

chitatel("Sa","Le",40310,5,"Moststroy").

chitatel("Ka","Te",21,4,"Bankir").

sr_vozrast(*):-chitatel(*,*,*,X,_),sum(Y),Z=X+Y,assertz(sum(Z)),
count(A), B=A+1, assertz(count(B)),fail.
sr_vozrast(Avg):- sum(X), count(Y), Avg=X / Y.

GOAL sr_vozrast(X),write(X).

Comment: sr_vozrast(здесь вроде должен стоять предикат):- .... ?

Comment: Немного путаете понятия, предикаты у нас либо факт, либо правило, либо цель.sr_vozrast(X)-предикат с одним выходным аргументом.